# Android - External Memory Card is not writeable from my app

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-developer-api

I need help in getting the attached memory card writable from my app.
The android version I'm using is Marshmellow. I requested for runtime permission using the below code.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
    } 

 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE) {
        if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission Granted");
        }
    }
}
```

I also checked the settings and the write permission is granted.
Below are the two storage locations I have for the phone

```
/storage/emulated/0 (Internal Memory, Writable)
/storage/9C33-6BBD (SDCard, Not writable, only readable)
```

I tried the below code just to check if my memory card is writable

```
File file = new File("/storage/9C33-6BBD");
file.canWrite() // returns false every time
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong, other apps seem to have no problem in writing to memory card.

I also used adb shell and was able to create a folder in my memory card.

I have also added the below permission in my Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Please let me know if you need more details. And thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a file in external sd card and not in device storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247666/how-to-write-a-file-in-external-sd-card-and-not-in-device-storage)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong

You do not have read/write access to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.

> other apps seem to have no problem in writing to memory card.

Those apps were pre-installed by the device manufacturer or custom ROM developer.

Or, those apps are using `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, or `getExternalMediaDirs()`. If those methods return 2+ locations, the second and subsequent ones are on removable storage, and you can read/write to those locations.

Or, those apps are using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, from [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html).

Or, those apps are exploiting some security flaw that, hopefully, will get fixed.